# images align with text

Tags: image, css, alignment

I would like to align 2 images wrapped with text but I haven't found any way to do it or any post that could help.

Something like this:

```
text text text text text  image1
text text text text text  image2
text text text text text  text t
text text text text text  text t
```

Comment: `float:right;clear:right;`...

Comment: can you give us the html layout you have ? What's the context ?

Comment: Wesley i tried with float: right; clear: right; and it positioned the images one on top of the other but above the text, that's not the behavior im expecting, you can see it here 
http://atencionintegraldevarices.com/tratamiento.php?id=9
what i need is the text on the left and the images on the right of the text, so when the text overtake the second image it gets above of it. Kind of like the second example on this http://www.echoecho.com/htmlimages08.htm , but with 2 images instead of 1

Comment: @DannyG: Put the images *first* in the HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place it in a table, or like Wesley Murch said, you can use the CSS float and clear properties (`float:right;clear:right;`) to move it to the right of the page and prevent text from appearing to the right of the images.